# Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I got the error

> Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework
>   'DNX,Version=v4.5.1': framework/fx/System.configuration 4.0.0.0

When I run a docker container. But it works fine in IIS.
The project file is

```
        {
      "webroot": "wwwroot",
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta6",
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "jqGridWebApi": "1.1.4",
        "EnyimMemcached": "2.13.0",
        "xunit": "2.2.0-beta1-build3239",
        "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205",
        "NLog": "2.1.0",
        "CryptSharpOfficial": "2.1.0",
        "System.Linq.Dynamic": "1.0.4"
      },
      "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5005"
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
          "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0",
            "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
          }
        }
      },
      "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
      ],
      "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
      ],
      "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "Staging": { }
      }
    }
```

My global.json file is

```
{
   "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
   "sdk": {
     "version": "1.0.0-beta6"
   }
}
```

And

[image: demo]

So why?

Comment: Beta 6 ! You should try to update your code to the RC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta 6 is no longer supported. Upgrading to RC1 should resolve the issue.